# how to determine x and y of blob after rotation and scaling with kinecticjs

Tags: kineticjs

I am using Kinecticjs v5.0.1 "kinect.line" (blobs), Is there a way to determine the new x,y points of a group after that group has been scaled and rotated?

I need to align text to rotated blobs - however if I make the text part of the group, it will be rotated as well.

What I want to do is determine the new x,y points of the rotated blob and move the text to that position, without it rotating.

Answer (score 1):

There are no Kinetic.Blob properties for the bounding box of a scaled and rotated blob.

**Finding the bounding box of a scaled, rotated Kinetic.Blob is complicated.**

Here are the steps...

**First: Get the control points of the cubic Bezier curves that make up the blob**

- The blob is actually a closed series of cubic Bezier curves.
- The starting point of the blob is the first 2 elements in blob.getPoints().
- The control points of each Bezier curve are in blob.getTensionPoints();
- These curves are the untransformed blob (no scaling, no rotation)

**Second: Get the bounding box of the untransformed blob:**

- Walk along every curve using the formula for a Cubic Bezier Curve.
- Determine the minimum-X/Y and maximum-X/Y for the set of curves.
- These min/max X,Y are the blobs bounding box if the blob is not scaled and not rotated.

**Third: Scale and rotate the X/Y point**

- Kinetic uses a transformation matrix to keep track of how any shape is scaled and rotated.
- A transformation matrix is a mathematical way of determining the X/Y of a point after it has been rotated and scaled.
- Get the transformation matrix for a blob using var matrix = blob.getAbsoluteTransform().
- Get the scaled/rotated XY of the bounding box corners by using blob.getTransform().getMatrix() where X,Y are the untransformed XY you calculated in the second step.

**Here is some useful code for you to piece together to achieve your result**

*This code will get the control points of a Kinetic.Blob and draw it on the canvas*

```
var points=blob.getPoints();
var tensionPoints=blob.getTensionPoints();
var ctx=layer.getContext()._context;
var x=blob.getX();
var y=blob.getY();

ctx.save();
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(points[0]+x,points[1]+y);
for(var i=0;i<tensionPoints.length-2;i+=6){
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(
        tensionPoints[i+0]+x,tensionPoints[i+1]+y,
        tensionPoints[i+2]+x,tensionPoints[i+3]+y,
        tensionPoints[i+4]+x,tensionPoints[i+5]+y
    );
}
ctx.lineWidth=5;
ctx.strokeStyle="red";
ctx.stroke();
ctx.restore();
```

*This utility will walk a cubic Bezier curve and return XY points along that curve*

In this utility:

- T=0.00 will return the XY of the starting point of the curve,
- T=1.00 will return the XY of the ending point of the curve,
- Incrementing T by .01 will usually yield an adequate sample of XY along the curve

Get XY along a cubic Bezier curve:

```
function getCubicBezierXYatT(startPt,controlPt1,controlPt2,endPt,T){
    var x=CubicN(T,startPt.x,controlPt1.x,controlPt2.x,endPt.x);
    var y=CubicN(T,startPt.y,controlPt1.y,controlPt2.y,endPt.y);
    return({x:x,y:y});
}

// cubic helper formula at T distance
function CubicN(T, a,b,c,d) {
    var t2 = T * T;
    var t3 = t2 * T;
    return a + (-a * 3 + T * (3 * a - a * T)) * T
    + (3 * b + T * (-6 * b + b * 3 * T)) * T
    + (c * 3 - c * 3 * T) * t2
    + d * t3;
}
```

*This utility will convert original XY to scaled/rotated XY using a transformation matrix*

```
// usage: var XY=tmPoint(trx.getMatrix(),oldX,oldY);

var trx=blob.getTransform();
var XY=tmPoint(trx.getMatrix(),oldX,oldY);

function tmPoint(m, x, y){
  return({
    x:x*m[0] + y*m[2] + m[4],
    y:x*m[1] + y*m[3] + m[5]
  });
}
```